# How to call Yoast Seo Tags without needing to call the whole wp_head?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast

A client wants to add SEO to his newsletter pages, that are linked to WP. (See at end) and wants those pages to be indexed, and have some SEO in them. I already got Yoast on the site, but I do not load WP_Head in the newsletters. So is there a way to call the SEO tags without grabbing the whole wp_head?

---

I create newsletters in the WP site so the client can create his newsletter by himself, then just grab the code and throw it in mailchimp or something like that.